# R - Insert Missing Numbers in A Sequence by Group's Max Value

Tags: r

I'd like to insert missing numbers in the index column following these two conditions:

1. Partitioned by multiple columns
2. The minimum value is always 1
3. The maximum value is always the maximum for the group and type

Current Data:

```
group   type    index   vol
A       1       1       200
A       1       2       244
A       1       5       33

A       2       2       66
A       2       3       2
A       2       4       199
A       2       10      319

B       1       4       290
B       1       5       188
B       1       6       573
B       1       9       122
```

Desired Data:

```
group   type    index   vol
A       1       1       200
A       1       2       244
A       1       3       0
A       1       4       0
A       1       5       33

A       2       1       0
A       2       2       66
A       2       3       2
A       2       4       199
A       2       5       0
A       2       6       0
A       2       7       0
A       2       8       0
A       2       9       0
A       2       10      319

B       1       1       0
B       1       2       0
B       1       3       0
B       1       4       290
B       1       5       188
B       1       6       573
B       1       7       0
B       1       8       0
B       1       9       122
```

I've just added in spaces between the partitions for clarity.

Hope you can help out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_df %>% 
  group_by(group, type) %>% 
  complete(index = 1:max(index), fill = list(vol = 0))

#    group type index vol
# 1      A    1     1 200
# 2      A    1     2 244
# 3      A    1     3   0
# 4      A    1     4   0
# 5      A    1     5  33
# 6      A    2     1   0
# 7      A    2     2  66
# 8      A    2     3   2
# 9      A    2     4 199
# 10     A    2     5   0
# 11     A    2     6   0
# 12     A    2     7   0
# 13     A    2     8   0
# 14     A    2     9   0
# 15     A    2    10 319
# 16     B    1     1   0
# 17     B    1     2   0
# 18     B    1     3   0
# 19     B    1     4 290
# 20     B    1     5 188
# 21     B    1     6 573
# 22     B    1     7   0
# 23     B    1     8   0
# 24     B    1     9 122
```

With `group_by` you specify the groups you indicated withed the white spaces. With `complete` you specify which columns should be complete and then what values should be filled in for the remaining column (default would be `NA`)

**Data**

```
my_df <- 
  structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                 type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                 index = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L), 
                 vol = c(200L, 244L, 33L, 66L, 2L, 199L, 319L, 290L, 188L, 573L, 122L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group, type) %>%
 complete(index = full_seq(1:max(index), 1), fill = list(vol = 0))

   group  type index   vol
   <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         1     1   200
 2 A         1     2   244
 3 A         1     3     0
 4 A         1     4     0
 5 A         1     5    33
 6 A         2     1     0
 7 A         2     2    66
 8 A         2     3     2
 9 A         2     4   199
10 A         2     5     0
11 A         2     6     0
12 A         2     7     0
13 A         2     8     0
14 A         2     9     0
15 A         2    10   319
16 B         1     1     0
17 B         1     2     0
18 B         1     3     0
19 B         1     4   290
20 B         1     5   188
21 B         1     6   573
22 B         1     7     0
23 B         1     8     0
24 B         1     9   122
```